# Is it possible to read ping command's message on the address you send the command to?

Tags: networking, ping

If let's say I use ping command in the form of `ping -p 'xyz' 1.1.1.1` can I read the pattern xyz on 1.1.1.1? Are there more ways in which you transmit data using ping command?

Comment: What shell are you running this from? What OS are you using? And in what language do you want to retrieve the `xyz` parameter? Please elaborate!

Comment: I'm using linux, using bash. Language does not matter as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
tcpdump -A icmp
```

on 1.1.1.1 you'll see the ping packets and their data.

Read the man page for `ping` to see all the options.

Comment: Or any other network sniffer; e.g., Ethereal.

Comment: I agree with Barmar completely.  I would have said this as well, especially the last sentence. All you literally have to do is the following: